# How get URL in CDI inteceptor for Jesey method call?

Tags: url, jersey, jax-rs, cdi

I am writing CDI Intercepter for Jersey method. Can I receive URL without adding argument with @Context annotation into Jersey method?

In JFS there is static method in FaseContext that can help to get Request for for current Thread (and I can get URL from it):

```
FaseContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest()
```

Is there some thing similar in Jersey?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a request listener and create a new thread local, or create a producer for it.